# centos: pam-mysql doesn't work as expected (cant login ssh with name/pwd from DB)

Tags: mysql, linux, authentication, mariadb, pam

My purpose is to login linux (ssh) with username/password stored in MariaDB.
I think it should work... but no!
HELP please! Anyone!

Environment: 
**OS** - CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) X86_64 
**database** - MariaDB 10.0.26 for Linux (x86_64) 
**pam_mysql** - version 0.7 release 0.21.rc1.el7.centos 
**libnss-mysql** - version 1.5 release 19.el7 

**NOTE**: username/password is stored in an existing table system.Admin

after googled, i found [this totur](https://support.asperasoft.com/hc/en-us/articles/216127348-Getting-PAM-to-authenticate-against-MySQL).
and i've looked in manuals: `/usr/share/doc/libnss-mysql-1.5/README` and `/usr/share/doc/pam_mysql-0.7/README`.

after all, what i did is edit several text files:

### 1. /etc/libnss-mysql-root.cfg:

```
username    root
password    628508320
```

### 2. /etc/libnss-mysql.cfg:

```
getpwnam    SELECT username,'x',id+10000,0,username, \
                CONCAT('/home/',username),'/bin/bash' \
            FROM Admin \
            WHERE (Admin.username='%1$s') \
            LIMIT 1
getpwuid    SELECT username,'x',id+10000,0,username, \
                CONCAT('/home/',username),'/bin/bash' \
            FROM Admin \
            WHERE (Admin.id=('%1$u'-10000)) \
            LIMIT 1
getspnam    SELECT username,password,'1','0','99999','0','0','-1','0' \
            FROM Admin \
            WHERE (Admin.username='%1$s') \
            LIMIT 1
getpwent    SELECT username,'x',id+10000,0,username, \
                CONCAT('/home/',username),'/bin/bash' \
            FROM Admin
getspent    SELECT username,password,'1','0','99999','0','0','-1','0' \
            FROM Admin
getgrnam    SELECT 'admin','admin',0
getgrgid    SELECT 'admin','admin',0
getgrent    SELECT 'admin','admin',0
memsbygid   SELECT username FROM Admin
gidsbymem   SELECT 0

host        localhost
database    system
username    root
password    628508320
```

### 3. /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
passwd:     files sss mysql
shadow:     files sss mysql
group:      files sss
```

### 4. /etc/pam.d/sshd

```
#%PAM-1.0

account sufficient  pam_unix.so
account required    pam_mysql.so   config_file=/etc/pam_mysql.cfg

auth    sufficient  pam_unix.so
auth    required    pam_mysql.so   config_file=/etc/pam_mysql.cfg
auth    required    pam_env.so

password    include system-auth
session     include system-auth
```

### 5. /etc/pam_mysql.cfg

```
users.host=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
users.db_user=root
users.db_passwd=628508320
users.database=system
users.table=Admin
users.user_column=username
users.password_column=password
users.password_crypt=1
verbose=0
```

### 6. now it should work, but it doesn't.

#### *addtional info:(hopes it help you to know what happened)*

```
[root@localhost ~]# mysql -p628508320 -e 'select id,username,password from system.Admin;'
+----+----------+---------------+
| id | username | password      |
+----+----------+---------------+
|  5 | admin    | VHeAzHjS/wVls |
|  6 | a        | rHscIjE3eNyHs |
|  7 | b        | b             |
+----+----------+---------------+
>> means that db is fine (password for admin is insert as encrypt('a') while b is plain)

[root@localhost ~]# id admin # user'admin' is not in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow
uid=10005(admin) gid=10005 groups=10005
>> seems that something works correct, `id` gets user from DB

[root@localhost ~] ssh admin@localhost
admin@localhost's password: 
Connection to localhost closed.

[root@localhost ~]# ls -ld /var/lib/mysql/ /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
drwxr-xr-x. 10 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 19 11:33 /var/lib/mysql/
srwxrwxrwx.  1 mysql mysql    0 Aug 17 10:55 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

After disabling selinux, i go through the mysql permission issue.

### now it failed at another point: (`tail -f /var/log/secure`)

```
Aug 20 17:24:37 MiWiFi-R1CM-srv sshd[70049]: Accepted password for admin from ::1 port 33322 ssh2
Aug 20 17:24:37 MiWiFi-R1CM-srv sshd[70049]: error: PAM: pam_open_session(): Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session
Aug 20 17:24:37 MiWiFi-R1CM-srv sshd[70049]: error: ssh_selinux_setup_pty: security_compute_relabel: Invalid argument
Aug 20 17:24:37 MiWiFi-R1CM-srv sshd[70049]: libnss-mysql: mysql_query failed: MySQL server has gone away, trying again (2)
Aug 20 17:24:37 MiWiFi-R1CM-srv sshd[70054]: Received disconnect from ::1: 11: disconnected by user
```

### UPDATE

I tried to use plain with `crypt=0` in /etc/pam_mysql.cfg,
i can log in, but the ui is odd: `-bash-4.2$` (i expected to be like `[root@localhost ~]#`) 
goole tell me to `cp -a /etc/skel /home/admin`, fixed.

Comment: `ls  -ld  /var/lib/mysql/  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: @RickJames thanks for reply! the result is added in the end of the question.

Comment: @RickJames after disabling selinux, the mysql '13 permission denied' error was fixed.

Comment: Oh, yes, SELinux:  http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?144,571990,572049